# Run html file in browser

Tags: html

I have an html file with approx. 5000 lines of css and 2000 of js. How can I render the file in the browser? The file can't be downloaded to the computer, so I can't use the traditional `file:///` to run locally. I also don't want to host it online. Is there another way?

Comment: where is this file, why can't you download it.

Comment: On this particular computer I'm not allowed to download any files so I have the html in a text doc

Comment: you can copy that code to another file as .html extension and then run it locally.

Comment: The file is not downloaded on your computer, nor is it hosted online.  You'll have to explain this paradox.

Comment: I can't do that, as I already said in the original question. I can't run the actual html. The options on this thing are very limited.

Comment: @ergonaut The html is saved in a text doc

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to splitting the file, I would suggest using `split -l 200 filename` command where `filename` is the name of your main file and `200` is the number of lines you want it in each file.